# Adding and removing class selector in angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a page header component whose styling I want to change depending upon the window scroll value. I want to add a class if the scroll value is greater than a certain value. I have the code in jquery.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 150) {
        $('.navbar').addClass('shrink');
    } else {
        $('.navbar').removeClass('shrink'); 
    }
});
```

> http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/z1Dx8

Till now, I am able to get the scroll value

```
renderer.listenGlobal('window', 'scroll', (event) => {
      const number = this.document.body.scrollTop;
      if (number > 150) {
        // add logic
      } else {
        // remove logic
      }
    });
```

I think I cannot use viewchild because I want to add/remove shrink from every html element just like the above jquery code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **angular2**'s [class binding](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#class-binding), in your code set a Boolean property to `true` or `false` depending on the scroll value, like this:

```
renderer.listenGlobal('window', 'scroll', (event) => {
  let number = this.document.body.scrollTop;

  this.addShrinkClass = number > 150;
});
```

And on your `.navbar` tag use the `[class.shrink]` binding as following:

```
<div class="navbar" [class.shrink]="addShrinkClass"></div>
```